# Why are values defined only once while using underscore in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's look at a few examples.

```
scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  val rand = new Random().nextInt
  _ + rand
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res0: Seq[Int] = List(-921709014, -921709013, -921709012)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  _ + new Random().nextInt
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res1: Seq[Int] = List(-884268781, 516035717, -2054776549)

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

Seq(1, 2, 3).map { i =>
  val rand = new Random().nextInt
  i + rand
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res2: Seq[Int] = List(-1258337635, 1817183115, -1994392)
```

Here, the values of `res0` were added to the same *random* number, suggesting that either the same random number was generated thrice (highly unlikely) or that only one random number was generated. `res1` looks as expected though which tells us direct function calls without assignment to a `val` generated random numbers as expected. Lastly `res2` *also* looks correct with the only difference being that a variable was used instead of using an `_`.

I am a having a hard time understanding why `res0` and `res2` differ in behavior. Especially, why doesn't `res0` behave as one would expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  val rand = new Random().nextInt
  _ + rand
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
// nextInt is outside the body of the function given to map
Seq(1, 2, 3).map({
  val rand = new Random().nextInt // nextInt evaluated once here (before map)
  i => i + rand                   // only this function given to map
})
```

The second:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  _ + new Random().nextInt
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
// nextInt is inside the body given to map
Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  i => i + new Random().nextInt 
}
```

Comment: Good question, I am not content with this answer yet. It is expected to give random number for every iteration (every value in the Seq), but not incrementing the initial evaluation result.

Answer (score 3):

Given your code:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map {
  val rand = new Random().nextInt
  _ + rand
}
```

That can be re-written as:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map({
  val rand = new Random().nextInt
  x => x + rand
})
```

Here you can see that the value `rand` is not calculated within the actual function definition `x => x + rand`. It is *closed in* from the context in which the function was defined. So basically it is a closure. So whenever the function `x => x + rand` is evaluated then the previously calculated `rand` value gets re-used.

For more details please have a look at the chapter [Functions and Closures](https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/functions-and-closures.html) (8.7 Closures) from the *Programming in Scala* book.

Comment: Are you sure? rand is not closure. Closures are declared outside the map call.

Comment: Closures are not only declared outside the ```map()``` function but also outside the definition of the anonymous function ```x => x + rand``` which is inside ```map()```. The block inside ```map({...})``` is only evaluated once! But its returned function many times. So ```rand``` is only defined once.

Comment: If map block is evaluated only once, I should get the same output in both cases. But the output differs. I have 2 methods defined same, one with "_" and one with named variable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678334/how-execution-of-same-function-defined-with-is-different-from-the-same-defin). I get different results. Is "evaluated" different from the "execution". May be I am understanding this differently. Thanks.

Comment: That is because of the one with the named variable defines that variable _outsite_ the function. So it is _closed in_.