# How execution of same function defined with "_" is different from the same defined with a named variable in Scala

Tags: scala

How execution of same function defined with "_" is different from the same defined with a named variable in Scala?

Here are outputs of both function definitions.

```
scala> import scala.util.Random
import scala.util.Random

scala> Seq("a", "b", "c").map(x => { val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x+":"+rand}).foreach(println)
a:1700883193
b:-1153799665
c:-784839760

scala> Seq("a", "b", "c").map({ val rand = new Random().nextInt;  _+":"+rand}).foreach(println)
a:-1775524209
b:-1775524209
c:-1775524209
```

Is it something related to partially defined functions? I may be missing something.

Explanation for appears-to-be-duplicate: I saw similar question asked, but the point is not made clear & noticed answers to a different point. So asking here with simple & straight example. The other question's link:
[Why are values defined only once while using underscore in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623764/why-are-values-defined-only-once-while-using-underscore-in-scal)
Hope it is clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are values defined only once while using underscore in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623764/why-are-values-defined-only-once-while-using-underscore-in-scala)

Comment: It appears like that, but both code snippets defined on other question are slightly different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't because of partial functions, it's the way [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) works. When you write:

```
_ + ":" + rand
```

The compiler interpets:

```
(x: String) => x.+(":").+(rand)
```

Which is a `Function1[String, String]`. The compiler expands the lambda expression into a concrete `AbstractFunction1` and *captures* `rand`. Here is the relevant snippet from the generated class:

```
<synthetic> <paramaccessor> private[this] val rand$1: Int = _;
  def <init>(rand$1: Int): <$anon: Function1> = {
    anonfun$1.this.rand$1 = rand$1;
    anonfun$1.super.<init>();
    ()
```

Note that `rand$1` gets assigned to a local field `this.rand$1` inside the generated `AbstractFunction1` instance. This field will be reused for each invocation of `map`, which is why you're not seeing a fresh value each iteration, but only *the first occurence*. You can see that in the byte code, the `init` method is only called once when running `main`:

```
public void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
     0: aload_0
     1: ldc           #16        // String he
     3: ldc           #18        // String hello
     5: new           #20        // class Chapter5/X$$anonfun$main$1
     8: dup
     9: invokespecial #21        // Method Chapter5/X$$anonfun$main$1."<init>":()V  <--- Here.
    12: invokespecial #25        // Method f$1:(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    15: pop
    16: return
```

Where `f$1` is the `main` method body which traverses the collection and calls `apply` for each element in the sequence.

On the contrary, when you introduce a fresh variable for each value in the collection like this:

```
map(x => { val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x+":"+rand})
```

We see that `rand` is no longer captured, by binded to a fresh variable for each invocation of `apply`:

```
@SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1 with Serializable {
    final def apply(x: String): String = {
      val rand: Int = new scala.util.Random().nextInt();
      x.+(":").+(scala.Int.box(rand))
    };
```

Comment: I am new to Closures, if _ evaluates to Closures, how does Seq(1, 2, 3).reduce(_+_) evaluate to 6 ?

Comment: @KiranM _ does not evaluate to a closure. Closure is when you *close over* a resource which can go out of scope before you invoke tge function. I suggest reading the wiki value I added to the post.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the block. `….map(x => { val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x+":"+rand }).…` can be rewritten to

```
val fn = x => { val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x+":"+rand })
….map(fn).…
```

while `….map({ val rand = new Random().nextInt;  _+":"+rand }).…` means the same as

```
….map({ val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x => x+":"+rand }).…
```

which can be rewritten to (notice the position of the `x =>`)

```
val fn = { val rand = new Random().nextInt;  x => x+":"+rand }
….map(fn).…
```

or (without the block)

```
val rand = new Random().nextInt
val fn = x => x+":"+rand
….map(fn).…
```

Comment: Not clear yet, "_" itself replaces the input argument(s). So for my code#2, I didn't pass "x", so "_" would take its place. [In other words, why "x" is used in your code snippet line (x => _+":"+rand). ] Thanks.

Comment: Ooops, I forgot to completely expand the `_`. I meant to use `x` there, fixed now.